# Can't install umbraco using nuget "operation failed"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, umbraco7

i'am new use umbraco cms after i try to install using nuget in visual studio 2012 i get this error

From nuget package

```
'Newtonsoft.Json' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'.
```

and this from nuget console

```
Install-Package : 'Newtonsoft.Json' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package UmbracoCms
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

I had this yesterday. You need to make sure your NuGet manager in Visual Studio is the latest version. On older versions, you'll get that error. Upgrading the NuGet manager fixed the error for me. See here for some more info: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-9848